# ActiveX OCX can register when built in release mode but not in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, activex

I'm running into an irritating problem.  Using Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 SP1 64-bit OS, I rebuilt an ActiveX control that has been working for years at a customer site.  It was built in Release mode.  But when I tested the control, it crashed.  I tried to build it in Debug mode, but it could not be registered.  The error message is:

"The module ... may not be comnpatible with the version of Windows that you're running.  Check if the module is conpatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe."

I tried registering it with both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of regsvr32, and got the same error with both of them.

I'd really like to be able to use the debugger with this control.  If I can't,  I'll have to just throw message boxes into my control until I can identify the spot where it's crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency Walker to Profile registering your OCX and see what it complains about. When registering any version of your OCX, appropriate versions of your dependencies must be available to your OCX. To Profile open the correct bitness regsvr32.exe into Dependency Walker, select Profile and enter the name of your OCX in the Program Arguments field.